# Command Usage in DMs | Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am making a bot that has a command where you can text people.

The point is you send a text through a server to a user, which the user will receive a DM with the contents. The user uses the command through the bot's DMs which will then send that message to the senders DMs.

Basically I need to know how to make it so the user can use the command through DMs and send a message back to the sender.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do if you don't use database is save the senderID who dm-ed someone through the command in server. And then take the senderID from the json get user from it and then save as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to send a dm

```
user.send("message here");
```

User is the user object and send is one of it's methods.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.